# Using "ref" or "out" in a extension

Tags: c#, extension-methods

anyone knows a way to solute this smart?

```
public static void Invert(this ref bool value)
{
    value = !value;
}
```

c# says i can not use "ref" or "out" within an extension. But such extensions like List.Clear() exist.

Comment: What `List.Clear()` extension do you mean?

Comment: `List<T>.Clear()` is not an extension method and doesn't take `ref` or `out` arguments. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @TimSchmelter just `myBool.Invert();`

Comment: No, the first argument to an extension method **cannot** be `ref` or `out`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List.Clear()` isn't an extension method, it's a method. And even if it was an extension method, it wouldn't need to receive the parameter as `ref`, because it doesn't "return" a different list than the one you had, it modifies the list.

And, in general, you can't. But you normally don't need to.

What about:

```
public static bool Invert(this bool value)
{
    return !value;
}

bool x = false.Invert();
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I know of no `List.Clear` extension method. `List<T>.Clear()` is a normal method. It has no `ref` parameters.

The second issue is that `List<T>` is a mutable reference type. So you can modify it, without changing the reference itself. You only need `ref` if you want to change the reference itself, or if you're working on a value type.